# i am very new to micro controller world. i am using pic16f877, please solve simple error in below description

Tags: mplab-x-5.50

i am getting error in this code ....can any body tell this solution

```
void interrupt ISR (void)

{

  if (RCIF == 1)     //*error: expected ';' after top level declarator***

  {
    UART_Buffer = RCREG; // Read The Received Data Buffer

    PORTB = UART_Buffer; // Display The Received Data On LEDs

    RCIF = 0; // Clear The Flag
  }
}
```

Comment: COuld you please [edit] your question and add more source code? The Error you are seeing is clearly not happening here. Sometimes an error like a missing `;` is shown in a different place

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.